# Coverage Class Test Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I have trigger before update and I have 48% code coverage
This is my code

```
public without sharing class Opp_CalculTotalForcast {

    public static void TotalForcast (List <Opportunity> oppList)
    {
        system.debug('debut: ' +oppList);  
        integer i;
        Decimal TotalForcastparc =0;
        Decimal TotalForcastcurrency = 0;
        Decimal TotalForcastDomPorc = 0;
        Decimal TotalForcastDomcurrency = 0;
        Decimal TotalForcastIntparc = 0;
        Decimal TotalForcastIntcurrency = 0;
        Integer Nb_BUs_participating = 0;

        list<Tender_BU_Response__c> allBUList = new list<Tender_BU_Response__c>();
        list<Tender_BU_Response__c> BUREPONSE = new list<Tender_BU_Response__c>();
        List<Decimal> nbrebu = new list <Decimal>();

        list<Opportunity> Opp = new list<Opportunity>();

      for(Opportunity o:oppList ) 
         { 
        for (Tender_BU_Response__c BUResp :[Select id,name, Total_Parcels_Forecast__c,Stage__c, Total_Revenues_Forecast__c, Domestic_Parcels_Forecast__c,Domestic_Revenues_Forecast__c,International_Parcels_Forecast__c,International_Revenues_Forecast__c from Tender_BU_Response__c where Tender__c =:o.id] )
          {
           system.debug('BURespname' +BUResp.name);
              Nb_BUs_participating = Nb_BUs_participating+1;
           o.Nb_BUs_participating__c = Nb_BUs_participating;

           TotalForcastparc= TotalForcastparc +BUResp.Total_Parcels_Forecast__c;
           o.Parcels_Forecasted__c = TotalForcastparc;

           TotalForcastcurrency = TotalForcastcurrency +  BUResp.Total_Revenues_Forecast__c; 
            o.Amount =TotalForcastcurrency;

          TotalForcastDomPorc = TotalForcastDomPorc +  BUResp.Domestic_Parcels_Forecast__c;
              o.Total_Forecast_Domestic_Parcels__c =TotalForcastDomPorc;
           TotalForcastDomcurrency   = TotalForcastDomcurrency + BUResp.Domestic_Revenues_Forecast__c;
               o.Total_Forecast_Domestic__c =TotalForcastDomcurrency;
           TotalForcastIntparc  = TotalForcastIntparc + BUResp.International_Parcels_Forecast__c;
              o.Total_Forecast_International_Parcels__c =TotalForcastIntparc;
          TotalForcastIntcurrency = TotalForcastIntcurrency + BUResp.International_Revenues_Forecast__c;
              o.Total_Foreast_International__c =TotalForcastIntcurrency;
           oppList.add(o); 
           BUREPONSE.add(BUResp);
          // nbrebu.add(o.Nb_BUs_participating__c);
           system.debug('BUResp' +BUResp);
          }

    }

    }
}
```

This is my test class:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class Opp_CalculTotalForcasttest {
@isTest
static void Opp_CalculTotalForcast_Test()
    {
          system.test.startTest();
          Profile p = [select id from profile where Name='System Administrator' limit 1];  
        User u = new User(alias = 'test3', email='testemail@gmail.com', emailencodingkey='ISO-8859-1', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='fr',   
        localesidkey='fr_FR_EURO', profileid = p.Id, timezonesidkey='Europe/Paris', username='test1834'+String.valueOf(date.today())+'@csc.com');   
        insert u;
          system.runAs(u){
          id  recordtypeid;
        List <recordtype> RecordtypeOpp= [Select id  from recordtype  where id =: Label.GATERFI  limit 1];
        if (RecordtypeOpp.size() > 0)
        {
            recordtypeid = RecordtypeOpp[0].id;
        } 
       Decimal TotalForcastparc =0;
        Decimal TotalForcastcurrency = 0;
        Decimal TotalForcastDomPorc = 0;
        Decimal TotalForcastDomcurrency = 0;
        Decimal TotalForcastIntparc = 0;
        Decimal TotalForcastIntcurrency = 0;
        Integer Nb_BUs_participating = 0; 
              DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(2014, 12, 16, 12, 6, 13);
     Date myDate = myDateTime.date();
     Id RecordTypeIdBUtypeAccount = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Account').getRecordTypeId();
        //Create new account  
     Account acc = new Account (Name = 'testdeaicha23', recordTypeId = RecordTypeIdBUtypeAccount);
     insert acc;
              system.debug('accid--' +acc.id);
      //create new opportunity      
     Opportunity opp = new Opportunity (AccountId = acc.id,Nb_BUs_participating__c=0, Name = 'opptestaicha',Comments__c ='test1', StageName = '0. Pre-Alert', CloseDate = myDate,Date_Received__c=Date.today(),Deadline_to_respond__c=Date.today());
    insert opp;   
   system.debug('oppid--' +opp.id);

   Tender_BU_Response__c  BURespons1 = new Tender_BU_Response__c();        
   BURespons1.Tier__c = acc.id;
    BURespons1.Tender__c=opp.id; 
    BURespons1.Name= 'BUtestaicha1';
    BURespons1.Domestic_Parcels_Forecast__c= 100;
    BURespons1.Domestic_Revenues_Forecast__c= 200; 
    BURespons1.International_Parcels_Forecast__c  = 400;
    BURespons1.International_Revenues_Forecast__c= 350;
    insert BURespons1;

   Tender_BU_Response__c  BURespons2 = new Tender_BU_Response__c();            
    BURespons2.Tier__c = acc.id;
    BURespons2.Tender__c=opp.id;
    BURespons2.Name= 'BUtestaicha2';
    BURespons2.Domestic_Parcels_Forecast__c= 100; 
    BURespons2.Domestic_Revenues_Forecast__c= 200;
    BURespons2.International_Parcels_Forecast__c  = 400; 
    BURespons2.International_Revenues_Forecast__c= 350;
    insert BURespons2;
    //opp.Comments__c= 'test2';
    //update opp;

   //Tender_BU_Response__c BU
   //
    List <Tender_BU_Response__c> Resp = [Select id,name, Total_Parcels_Forecast__c,Stage__c, Total_Revenues_Forecast__c, Domestic_Parcels_Forecast__c,Domestic_Revenues_Forecast__c,International_Parcels_Forecast__c,International_Revenues_Forecast__c from Tender_BU_Response__c where Tender__c =: opp.id];          
    system.debug('Resp' +Resp);
    opp.Nb_BUs_participating__c = 2;
    opp.Parcels_Forecasted__c =100;
    update opp;
   system.debug('oppid2 ' +opp.id); 
   }
    } 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The highlighting in your code coverage screenshot shows that test execution never enters the loop

```
for (i=0; i < BUREPONSE.size(); i++) {
```

You have not included this code in your question (it's a different set of code than the non-test code you included), so we cannot say exactly why that might be except that your test data is not designed properly to cause `BUREPONSE` to be populated with data that would match each of the `if` conditionals in the loop, which is what you'll need to do in order to achieve full coverage.

Note also that `List.size()` will never return `null`. You should be checking for `0`, although iterating over a zero-size loop is a no-op, so it's not critical to do that check unless you explicitly index into the loop `BUREPONSE[i]`.

Finally, your tests are completely meaningless without making assertions about your code's behavior. You need to verify that the code does what it claims to do, *not* just get code coverage. For more, see the [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing) Trailhead module.